# can not generate resource nestjs : typeScript

Tags: typescript, npm, nestjs, yarnpkg

I am getting this error:

> ```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'properties' of undefined
>
> Failed to execute command: 
> node @nestjs/schematics:resource --name=post --no-dry-run --language="ts" --sourceRoot="src" --spec
> ```

What I’ve tried so far:

```
npm i -g @nestjs/schematics
```

and

```
npm install --save-dev webpack-cli@3.1.1
```

but they also did not work.

Issue when creating new resources with nest g resource

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "nestjs",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@hapi/joi": "^17.1.1",
    "@nestjs/common": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^2.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/mapped-types": "*",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^8.2.1",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^8.0.3",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.2",
    "@types/hapi__joi": "^17.1.8",
    "@types/passport-jwt": "^3.0.6",
    "@types/passport-local": "^1.0.34",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "passport": "^0.5.2",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "pg": "^8.7.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.2.0",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.45"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "27.4.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "^27.2.5",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.20",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.3",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.10.1",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

**ts config**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false
  }
}
```

**Edit:** I have also tried the following that didn’t work:

```
npx nest g resource post
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

actually my project was not updated . and i also update some dependencies not all .due to this it is not working .

so i update project with this

```
nest update -f -t latest
```

or

```
yarn upgrade-interactive --latest
```

after that install

```
yarn global add @nestjs/schematics
```

now it's working fine

Comment: Since v9.0.0 release, the command update was removed. To upgrade your dependencies, you can use dedicated tools like ncu   (https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates)
ncu -u
or use
yarn upgrade-interactive

Answer (score 12):

I had similar issue. in my case my global and local nest cli version were out of sync. I ran

```bash
npm  i -g @nestjs/cli
```

Everything works fine now

Comment: This fixed my issue - 2023 Apr with M1 Mac